# Какое событие происходит после вызова метода html() в jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript, события

Здравствуйте. Мне надо прописать событие при изменении внутреннего наполнения элемента.

```
$("#Preview").htmlChanged(function() {});
```

Что-то такое. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, только зря в комментарием. Могли бы 10 баллов получить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

похожий вопрос и хороший метод его решения:

Отловить программное изменение input'a

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю - никак.